# Android: Switch case in toast alert Dialog

Tags: android

Android: Switch case in toast alert Dialog.

I want to get the string on return. Here is my code:

```
public String getValue(final int x) {

    final String[] c = new String[1];


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
                    {"1", "2", "3"},
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                    // of the selected item
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            Toast.makeText(context, "clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            c[0] = "1";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Toast.makeText(context, "clicked 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            c[0] = "2";

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Toast.makeText(context, "clicked 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            c[0] = "3";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();

    return c[0];
}
```

However it does not return anything!

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: try returning the items within switch instead of break and remover the return statement from the bottom

Comment: I tried as you suggested but it says that "Can not return o value from a method with the void return type".

Comment: Listener will return value only after click, so it will not be called immediatelly after creating it. On creating of this builder the switch part will be skipped, so c[0] will not be modifed

Comment: The dialog itself provides its data only when you actually click the button on the dialog.  It does not wait for you. It is not synchronous.  Your code will most likely return the previously selected value in that method only.

Answer (score 2):

the `onClick` has return typo void, so there is no change that you can return a value from there, without causing a compile time error. What you could do is to create a method that process the input, and call it from the onClick. E.g.

```
public void myMethod(String input) {
   // do something with input
}
```

and call it

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                // of the selected item
                switch (which) {
                   // cases
                }
                myMethod(c[0]);
               // the other code
```

Comment: Thank you alot. What should I put in the myMethod method?